# Minimization optimization - where have I gone wrong?

Tags: roots, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

Following @littleO's advice, I've set about to minimize $\sum_n ((x-x_n)^2+(y-y_n)^2+(z-z_n)^2-d^2)^2$. Going using an exact Hessian (because the function is smooth definite) as follows:

$\textbf{H} = 4 * \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_n [2(x-x_n)^2 + ((x-x_n)^2+(y-y_n)^2+(z-z_n)^2-d_n^2)] && \sum_n 2(x-x_n)(y-y_n) && \sum_n 2(x-x_n)(z-z_n) \\
\sum_n 2(y-y_n)(x-x_n) && \sum_n [2(y-y_n)^2 + ((x-x_n)^2+(y-y_n)^2+(z-z_n)^2-d_n^2)] && \sum_n 2(y-y_n)(z-z_n) \\
\sum_n 2(x-x_n)(z-z_n) && \sum_n 2(y-y_n)(z-z_n) && \sum_n [2(z-z_n)^2 + ((x-x_n)^2+(y-y_n)^2+(z-z_n)^2-d_n^2)] \end{bmatrix}$

and gradient:

$\nabla F = 4 \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_n (x-x_n)((x-x_n)^2+(y-y_n)^2+(z-z_n)^2-{d_n}^2) \\
\sum_n (z-z_n)((x-x_n)^2+(y-y_n)^2+(z-z_n)^2-{d_n}^2) \\
\sum_n (z-z_n)((x-x_n)^2+(y-y_n)^2+(z-z_n)^2-{d_n}^2)
\end{bmatrix}$

I'm still taking the barycenter of points $(x_n, y_n, z_n)$ as initial guess, and calculating the next step with $\textbf{x}_{n+1} = \textbf{x}_n - H^{-1} \nabla F$.

The current code, which should run as-is, can be found on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/srenauld/5fe7c1d7236716f0396b).

I'm pretty sure something still went wrong, however. While building this, I added a maximum deviation from expected values (which is really $\max{ f_n(\textbf{x}_{guess})}$). I expect this to decrease as I iterate closer and closer to a minimum. However, this is not the case. Not only am I see seriously weird iterations (convergence within 5 iterations to a value that is 4200km away from one base station - theoretically impossible), but the converging value itself makes little to no sense.

I get the impression I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: What optimization problem are you solving?  In other words, what objective function are you minimizing?

Comment: @littleO: $err_n = 0 \forall n$. In other words, where my perceived distance from all reference points ($d_n$) minus the distance from the receiver to the guess point is zero, or as close to zero as possible.

Comment: You can do checks on your solution. You can also check if your Jacobian becomes singular.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking at this as trying to solve the system of equations $d_n = \sqrt{(x - x_n)^2 + (y - y_n)^2 + (z - z_n)^2}$ for $n = 1,2,\ldots$.  And you're using Newton's method for solving nonlinear systems to try to solve this.  However, you don't expect to find an exact solution, because there isn't one.  I think you should instead solve some optimization problem such as minimizing $\sum_n ((x - x_n)^2 + (y - y_n)^2 + (z - z_n)^2 - d_n^2)^2$.  This objective function is differentiable so you can use the version of Newton's method that does optimization.

Comment: @littleO: You're correct - also, I know there is no exact solution; my aim is to try to find an approximate solution. I will implement what you've suggested (which is a smart idea, totally did not think of that). What I was most puzzled by in my attempt is how large $d\textbf{p}$ was - for a problem which is bounded to a 60km by 60km grid, I never expected it to reach in the thousands of kilometres.

Comment: There are a few issues with Newton's method to be aware of.  First, it depends on the initial guess, and can diverge if the initial guess is not good enough.  Second, there are two versions of Newton's method: one for solving nonlinear systems of equations, and one for solving optimization problems.  Newton's method for nonlinear systems assumes there is a solution to the system.  Third, Newton's method makes certain smoothness assumptions which might not be satisfied when the square root function is involved.

Comment: @littleO: took your advice and rewrote everything. I'm seeing a different behaviour now - convergence...to a theoretically impossible value. :(

Comment: If you plot the objective function value versus iteration, does it seem to be decreasing nicely?

Comment: One way you can check for bugs is to compute the gradient and Hessian numerically, using finite differences, and check that you have agreement with your analytic expressions.

Comment: Newton's method for minimization should use a [stepsize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization#Higher_dimensions), so the iteration is really $x_{n+1} = x_n - t H^{-1} \nabla f(x_n)$, where $0 < t < 1$.  There are line search procedures you can use to adaptively choose the step size at each iteration.

Comment: @littleO - I went through a systematic review of everything that goes into distance measurement and found a stray bug. Turns out I was not converting GPS coordinates to radians before running ECEF conversions. Everything now neatly converges! Your objective function was the key to it, though. If you want the rep, submit an answer and I'll be happy to set it as the right one :)

Comment: Oh great, I'm glad it's working!

Comment: Random comment while we are still looking at this post: I think there's a typo and some of the $ d $'s should be $ d_n$ instead. Might be worth correcting for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just recording my comment here so that this question receives an answer:

The suggestion was to minimize
\begin{equation}
\sum_n ((x - x_n)^2 + (y - y_n)^2 + (z - z_n)^2 - d_n^2)^2
\end{equation}
using Newton's method.